# Why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}\ n} =\log (2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone explain me this equation? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}\ n} =\log (2)$$
I am to calculate the sum of the expression on the left side. I was looking for mathematical formulas, any templates, but nothing was found. Have you got any idea?

Comment: Hint: think about how you might evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^n} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$

Comment: Consider the Taylor series for $\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Another method: Integrate both sides of sum of x^n/2^n = x/2/[1-x/2], manipulate terms a little and then substitute 1 for x.

Comment: @AntonioVargas do you have another hint? I'm interested in how you proceed on from there

Comment: @DanZimm, See [MathFacts' answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879008/5531) for more :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since:
$$ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\int_{0}^{x} y^n\,dy,$$
you have:
$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1/2} y^{n-1}\,dy = \int_{0}^{1/2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}y^n\,dy = \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{dy}{1-y}=\left.-\log(1-y)\right|_{0}^{1/2}=\log 2.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very helpful ;)

Comment: This is a beautiful presentation of this!

Comment: @oliveeuler no, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n2^n} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \int_0^{1 / 2} y^{n-1} dy$

Comment: @DanZimm I'd missed that the $y^{n}$ changed to $y^{n-1}$; my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n2^n} \quad \Rightarrow \quad f^{\prime}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{2^n} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x/2)^n = \frac{x/2}{x(1 - x/2)} = \frac{1}{2 - x}
$$
Thus,
$$
f(x) = -\ln (2 - x) + C
$$
For $x = 0$, $C = \ln 2$ and $f(x) = \ln \frac{2}{2 - x}$.

For $x = 1$, we have
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n2^n} = f(1) = \ln 2
$$